# How to use SAS macro in a SAS Dataset

Tags: sas

I want to use a Macro call in a data step. Below is the macro and its invocation in a data step but this isnt working. Can you guys please suggest a way to make it work.

```
 %macro xscan(string, delimiter, word_number);

 %let len1=%length(&string); /*Computing the length of the string*/
 %let len=%eval(&len1+1);
 %let sub=%scan(&string,&word_number,"&delimiter"); 

 %if &word_number ge 0 %then %do;
 %let pos=%index(&string,&sub); /* Locate the position while reading left to right*/
 %end;

 %if &word_number lt 0 %then %do;
 data _null_;
 pos=find("&string","&sub",-&len);
 call symput("pos",pos);
 run;
 %end;

 %let strg=%substr(&string,&pos); /* Extract the substring*/

 %put the string is &strg;
 %mend;

 data work.in_data;
length in_string $50;
in_string = “a bb ccc dddd bb eeeee”; 
output;
in_string = “aa b cc aa dee”; 
output;
 run;

 data work.out_data;
set work.in_data;
length sub_str $50;
start_word_num = -(_n_ +1);
sub_str = %xscan(in_string,’ ‘, start_word_num);
 run;

 proc print; run;
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** and include valid code to reproduce it. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance. It would also help if you described what it **should** do.

Comment: Indeed.  Simply dumping your code and saying it doesn't work is not sufficient; this needs to be posed as a problem that is sufficiently generalized that someone else might learn from it as well.

Comment: If you would like to build a function to be used in a datastep look into `PROC FCMP` rather than trying to use a macro to do it.  Also, re-read the answer and comments to the other question you asked because it looks like you don't fully understand what was said there.

Answer (score 2):

If the macro is to be used inside a datastep, write it more simply using just datastep functions instead of making it complicated with macro functions. There are plenty of SAS string functions which will allow you to accomplish what it appears you want in far less code.

Answer (score 0):

Data steps are very flexible and they allow you to manipulate your data in a very flexible day, I would recommend you trying to refactor the code to use only a datastep, however, if you  still want to use it the way you have it right now use `call execute` .
Here is an example:

```
data _null_ ;
input name $ value !$ ;
call execute
( ‘%global ‘
llname~l ‘;’ II
‘%let’ Ilnamell =’ [1
value II ‘;’
);
cards ;
abc xyz
;
```

Refer to these docs for further reading  : 
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/154-30.pdf and 
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi22/CODERS/PAPER70.PDF

Comment: In the OPs case, `call execute` will not work because the macro function isn't pure macro code, it contains data steps etc.  If he were to correct that this approach would be fine.